# Trouble connecting to a webservice from a android application

Tags: java, android, http

I'm developing a mobile app in android, and I'm using Httptriever to get information from a web service but it gives me a `connection to url refuses` error. I can connect from a browser perfectly. I'm using a local IP address which refers to a localhost address for the project.

any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: post the sample code which you have tried?

Comment: `@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... b) {
String url = getString(R.string.serveur);
String l = email.getText().toString();
   String p = password.getText().toString();
   
   url += "/UserLogin/?email="+l+"&password="+p;
HttpRetriever hr = new HttpRetriever();
return hr.retrieve(url); 
  }`

Comment: Looks like a network problem. Have you tried with a different computer with a different IP?

Comment: Post the output of logcat and the code you are using.

Comment: @PbxMan yes I have tried with different IPs but still the same problem

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom it's to long

Comment: Thanks I solve the problem it's just stupid my computer and my smarthpone are not in the same network :(